# Requests to endpoints return nothing

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to get a simple node, express, mongodb example working. I'm making the following requests with Postman, but can't get anything to return though.

GET `http://localhost:5000/test`

POST `http://localhost:5000/test?testMe=Tested!`

I'm also using nodemon in development. The following is returned in the console.

```
$ nodemon server
[nodemon] 1.19.4
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching dir(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node server.js`
Server is running on 5000
MongoDB database connection established successfully.
```

When making get and post requests, nothing is logged to the console, other than what is above.

I have the following directory structure

```
models\test.model.js
routes\test.js
.env
server.js
```

test.model.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const testSchema = new Schema({
  testMe: [String],
});

const Test = mongoose.model('Test', testSchema);

module.exports = Test;
```

routes\test.js

```
const router = require('express').Router();
let Test = require('../models/test.model');

// endpoint localhost:5000/test
router.route('/').get((req, res) => {
  console.log('GET:', res);

  Test.find()
    .then(dbData => res.json(dbData))
    .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error: ', err));
});

// endpoint localhost:5000/test
router.route('/').post((req, res) => {
  const testMe = req.body.testMe;
  console.log('testMe', testMe);

  const newTest = new Test({
    testMe
  });

  newTest.save()
    .then(test => {
      res.json(test);
      console.log('save', test, res);
    })
    .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error: ', err));
});


module.exports = router;
```

server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

require('dotenv').config();

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json);

const uri = process.env.ATLAS_URI;
mongoose.connect(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true, useCreateIndex: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });
const connection = mongoose.connection;
connection.once('open', () => {
  console.log("MongoDB database connection established successfully.")
});

const practiceRouter = require('./routes/practice'); // locations of routes file
app.use('/practice', practiceRouter); // directs the url path to the routes file

const testRouter = require('./routes/test');
app.use('/test', testRouter); 

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server is running on ${port}`));
```

Does anyone know what is going on? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

- are you missing importing the test route in your app?
- make sure the mongodb can be connected without problem
- you will need to update the route registering in test as this https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html.

  router.get('/', (req,res,next)=>{})

  router.post('/', (req,res,next)=>{})

Comment: I made index.js and managed to get a simple `app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Hello World!'))` working. I couldn't get the same thing working in server.js, so I guess there is a problem with server.js somehow.

Comment: Ok, I found it. Lol, I have wasted so many hours with this problem and got no syntax errors or warnings. The culprit was `app.use(express.json());` 
Thanks anyway for the advice :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  router.get('/', function (req, res) {
     Test.find()
        .then(dbData => res.json(dbData))
        .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error: ', err));
    });
```

Comment: I get nothing. I just realised, it's probably something to do with my set up. I started with create-react-app and then tried to get a database and routes integrated.

Comment: please remove // endpoint localhost:5000/test with post and try